# How can I grab a unique entity set using Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 4 classes I am trying to link together:

- ComponentType

  - id
  - Name
  - ...
- Component

  - Id
  - ComponentTypeID
  - ...
- RigAction

  - id
  - RigActionTypeID (pointing to RigActionType below)
  - ComponentID (pointing to component above)
- RigActionType

  - Name
  - ...

I am trying to create a table that lists all of the component types, and any actions assigned to them. (I cannot assign action types directly because of other properties that must remain unique)

I am attempting to query a list of unique RigActions based on their type ID (so that I don't have duplicate rig action types showing up) using Linq. Here is what I have so far, but it does not seem to be working. Hopefully what I am trying to accomplish makes sense...

**quick notes**

I have omitted anything i believed to be non relevant with this class, if you need more to go on, let me know and I can provide the entire class.

I have also tried setting this up as an EntitySet, rather than a list, but couldn't figure that out either (that is how I would prefer to do this if possible)

```
public class ComponentType
{
    public List<RigActionType> RigActionTypes = new List<RigActionType>();
    public void GetRigActionTypes()
    {
        this.RigActionTypes = this.Components.SelectMany(component => component.RigActions).GroupBy(a => a.RigActionType).Select(at => at.All()).ToList();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'All' takes '0' arguments
```

Comment: its clear, you need an lambda expression as delegate to call `at.All()`, which accept an `IGrouping` , and must return a `boolean` value

Comment: I don't think All is what you're trying to do here. To clarify you're requirements, you want these grouped by RigActionType only? Should they also be grouped by ComponentId? Also, do you want these as a grouping, or do you just want a distinct list (ignoring others that match the same type)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`All` is not what you are looking for - this methods helps to verify that all elements in the collection satisfy some condition.

If you want just one action per group (that is one action per action type) you can use First for example (at least this is what I derived from your problem description):

```
this.Components.SelectMany(component => component.RigActions)
               .GroupBy(a => a.RigActionType)
               .Select(at => at.First()).ToList();
```

However you property suggests that you want to hav a collection of all action types, right? In that case use Distinct:

```
this.RigActionTypes = this.Components.SelectMany(component => component.RigActions)
                                     .Select(a => a.RigActionType)
                                     .Distinct()
                                     .ToList();
```

Or you can stick to grouping approach:

```
this.RigActionTypes = this.Components.SelectMany(component => component.RigActions)
                                     .GroupBy(a => a.RigActionType)
                                     .Select(at => at.Key)
                                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Nailed it - I appreciate your completeness.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that `All` cannot be used without a delegate expression within it (e.g. `All(x => x.Something == 1)`) but in your case it's not needed.

This will get a list of the unique action types:

```
public void GetRigActionTypes()
{
    this.RigActionTypes = this.Components.SelectMany(component => component.RigActions.RigActionTypes).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

If you are looking for something else, please clarify.

Comment: Your solution worked like a champ, and I sincerely appreciate your answer. I marked @Andrei as the accepted answer, only because of the added detail. Seriously though - thanks!